# reorder columns at different levels in pandas pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The dataframe shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(3), columns=['tr','ca','cy','value'])
df.loc[0] = [1,1,'x',20]
df.loc[1] = [1,0,'y',300]
df.loc[2] = [0,0,'x',300]
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(np.int)
```

which results in

```
  tr ca cy  value
0  1  1  x     20
1  1  0  y    300
2  0  0  x    300
```

can be pivoted as

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['tr'], columns=['ca','cy'], fill_value=0)
```

which results in

```
ca    0        1
cy    x    y   x
tr
0   300    0   0
1     0  300  20
```

I need the order of 1/0 for `tr` and `ca` reversed.  I realize I can do `pt.loc[[1,0],]` and that gets me `tr` in the right order.  How do I do this for `ca`?  The answer I am hoping for is

```
ca   1    0     
cy   x    x    y
tr
1   20    0  300
0    0  300    0
```

Comment: could you please show the final output ... how are you expecting it? how the final df should look like

Comment: `pt[[1,0]].loc[[1,0]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use basic indexing provided by pandas like `pt[[1,0]].loc[[1,0]]` or if you want to deal with specific index in that multi index try reindexing i.e

```
pt.reindex(level='ca',columns=[1,0]).reindex(index=[1,0])

ca   1    0     
cy   x    x    y
tr              
1   20    0  300
0    0  300    0
```